# argparse optional positional argument determinded choices

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, optional-arguments

I presume this might be beyond what argparse can do, but maybe someone knows a pretty trick.

I want my first argument to be positional, optional and only get consummed if it is in a list of choices. If not consummed it should get a default value.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('myoption', nargs='?', choice=['a', 'b', 'c'], default='a')
```

Then I want to catch the rest of the arguments to use them in another command.

```
parsed, rest = parser.parse_known_args()
myoption = parsed.myoption
```

But I am still forced to pass an argument among the choices a,b,c as first positional argument.
For example this works

```
python myprog.py a things to pipe to another command
```

but this doesn't

```
python myprog.py things to pipe to another command
python myprog.py -m things to pipe to another command
```

and raises

> argument type: invalid choice: 'things' (choose from 'a', 'b', 'c')

I also tried to use `parser.parse_known_intermixed_args()` but it doesn't work.

How can I get argpasre to ignore the positional arguments that are not in the list of choices ? Is there a nice way to hack this while preserving argparse automatic outputs like error messsages and help display ?

Comment: You are basically describing a standard subcommand. What is the benefit of making `a` optional? What if `a` is a valid argument to "pipe to another command"?

Comment: argparse 'consumes' an argument and then checks if it fits the choices.  It does not parse based on value.

Comment: @chepner I didn't hink about the case where the optional `a` could be valid for the next command. Even if basicaly I could just build my cli such that this does not happend since I know the undelrying command. But it a least now makes sense why this is not part of the design of argparse.